# Software to put pages of a PDF file in book-order

Tags: linux, web-apps, pdf, printing, desktop-publishing

Is there a Linux or web-based tool to sort pages of a PDF document so I can print a book from it?

In this case, I have an A5-format PDF that I want to print on A4 pages, like this:

```
 ___________              ___________
|           |            |           |
| 99     1  | other side |  2     98 |
|___________|            |___________|
then
 ___________
|           |
| 97     3  | ... and so on
|___________|
```

Comment: I would think that you could print a normal PDF, and set your page layout to be that of a book. But then, I hate printers, so I'm no expert on this.

Comment: Doing it manually could be done with the default "Preview" app on Mac, but would be extremely tedious. I expect that Linux or Windows would be just as tedious. I once wrote an app to do this for Postscript, so I suppose you could use pdf2ps, then my app, then ps2pdf. Unfortunately, I can't find my app at the moment. _Edit:_ it looks like psbook does the same thing as my app.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am going to second the psbook recommendations but add this as a separate answer to note some of the complexities and what would be lost in what you are doing.  Chances are this is not a problem (I assume you are trying to *print* the book, not click on pages with a mouse) but basically this limits you to the PDF features available in Postscript (no hyperlinks etc) and to note one possible alternative (depending on what exactly you are trying to do).

In general, the printing of signaitures is somewhat complicated.  You don't have  1, 99, 2, 98, 3, 97  etc.  Instead you have 1, 2, 99, 98, 3, 4, 97, 96 (or 1, 99, 2, 3, 98, 97 if starting on the other page) if you are only printing double sheets two sided.  Additionally you have the issue that this assumes you aren't folding and cutting signatures (only folding them).  It looks like psbook only handles the fold and bind method, not the fold, cut, and bind method (with fold/cut/bind, chances are you'd print on A0 paper, 32 sheets to a signature, then cut and fold, so one sheet would become one signature).

There aren't any tools specifically for this that I know of directly in pdf format.

One thing to keep in mind is that if you are generating PDF's yourself from LaTeX, the following is likely to be more flexible and helpful: [booklet.sty](http://ctan.cermin.lipi.go.id/macros/latex/contrib/booklet/booklet.pdf)

That gives you a much richer set of options for printing signatures.

Answer (score 6):

As noted in the comments, it might well be the printer driver handles that: watch out for an option like "booklet".

Apart from that, you might be able to combine several command line utilities, which are part of the [Ghostscript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghostscript) package (at least on Ubuntu):

- [`pdf2ps`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/pdf2ps.1.html) converts your PDF into the PostScript format
- [`psbook`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/psbook.1.html) does the job you've asked for (rearrange pages in PostScript file into signatures)
- [`ps2pdf`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/ps2pdf.1.html) converts the PS back to PDF

From the `psbook` man page:

> Psbook rearranges pages from a PostScript document into ``signatures'' for printing books or booklets, creating a new PostScript file. The input PostScript file should follow the Adobe Document Structuring Conventions.

Comment: I am a bit expecting `psbook` to also put the pages side by side (making it complete foolproof), but I found that `psbook` shuffles the order of the pages only.

Comment: @Bernhard, what you are looking for is psnup.

Answer (score 6):

#### On the command line

You can use [Pdfjam](http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/statistics/staff/academic-research/firth/software/pdfjam/). This is a front-end for [PDFLaTeX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX), so you need a LaTeX installation. This isn't difficult to install on Linux (just let your package manager pull in the dependencies), but it will cost a few hundred MB of storage. The command is:

```
pdfbook foo.pdf
```

with the output going to `foo-book.pdf`, or `pdfbook --output book.pdf foo.pdf` if you want to control the output file name.

With older versions of Pdfjam (before 2.06), you need an additional option:

```
pdfbook --booklet true foo.pdf
```

#### With a GUI

This doesn't seem to be commonly available as a pre-configured printing option.
There is a [wishlist item](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=275466) in Okular. You can [create a printing filter](http://wiki.scribus.net/canvas/How_to_make_a_booklet) in KDE.
For Gnome, the [official advice](https://help.gnome.org/users/evince/unstable/print-booklet.html.en) is to list the page order manually!

You can install [PdfBooklet](http://pdfbooklet.sourceforge.net/). It isn't officially supported on Linux, and I haven't tried; however, it's a Python script, so it should work (install the [pyPdf](http://pybrary.net/pyPdf/) library through your package manager).

[Acrobat Reader](http://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/print-booklets-acrobat-reader.html) has booklet printing in its print options, under “Page Handling”.

Answer (score 2):

The following little tool written in Java worked just perfectly:
http://quantumelephant.co.uk/bookbinder/bookbinder.html

> Bookbinder is a program that will convert a PDF document into signatures suitable for traditional bookbinding.
> While there are a lot of programs on the net that will create a single booklet from a small document, I couldn't find one that would turn a 500 page novel or textbook into several signatures. So I had to write one.
> The chosen PDF is split into chunks, the page order of each chunk is rearranged, then the pages are placed two to a page in a new PDF. After printing and folding, each bundle of sheets should be a correctly ordered signature, ready for binding.

[image]

[image]

> The program is released under the same license as itext, a mixture of Mozilla Public License and GNU Library General Public License.

Answer (score 0):

Among other utilities I found this software, [Print House PDF Sorter here](http://messiahpsychoanalyst.org/Documents/Downloads.html#part11).

> A Software to Assist Putting Pages of a PDF Document into Print-house Order for Printing as a Book. This software can arrange pages of a PDF document sorted in way to come as sheets of a book ready to be stapled at the middle.
>
> Pages should be in A4 standard portrait size (please resize and put in portrait form using this page PDF Merger R6 resizing feature) and result will come as an A4 landscape accommodating each two pages in one sheet.
>
> There are four schemes for the second sheets depending on the technology of your printer or your desired manual feed. Select scheme by testing your printer with couple of sheets.

[image]

This software as I tried does not read PDFs secured by passwords

One of the schemes is like this,

[image]

The software is free, need notpay anything and should be cross platform.

Answer (score 0):

PdfCpu works great:

```
pdfcpu booklet out.pdf 2 essay.pdf
```

https://pdfcpu.io/generate/booklet